# What happens while predicting using a model when preprocessing layer is inside the model itself?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science, tensorflow-lite

While training if we apply preprocessing like horizontal flip inside the model itself won't it affect the data while its predicting?

so whats a work around to this or will it not matter if the augmentations are done on predictions as well?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to separate the data augmentation process from the model itself: apply it only during training, and not when the model is used for inference. For some models, certain types of augmentation at inference time (test-time augmentation) may be beneficial, but this depends heavily on the specific problem and model.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didnt know how I could map with datasets     ( tf.dataset.map(augmentations) )  once i knew this i solved the issue!